# Printing contents of file but prints a bunch of question marks infinitely on Linux

Tags: c, linux, file

I am trying to make a program that prints the contents of a file but whenever I try to run it, it just prints a bunch of question marks infinitely and this only happens when I run it on a UTM virtual machine (Linux terminal). It works fine when I run it on my Mac terminal so I am not sure if it has to do with the virtual machine or my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // input from user
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Too many/no arguments!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *fname;
    fname = argv[1];
    // Open file
    FILE *fdin = fopen(fname, "r");
    char ch = fgetc(fdin);
    while (ch != EOF) {
        printf("%c", ch);
        ch = fgetc(fdin);
    }
    fclose(fdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Image: [image: output/result]

The text file is just **input.txt** and the content is:

```
HELLOOO!!
```

but it prints a bunch of question marks infinitely. Works fine on my Mac terminal(M1) and it prints `HELLOOO!!` just fine without errors. It just doesn't work on my UTM Virtual Machine (Linux)

Comment: Try changing the type of `ch` to `int`.

Comment: Please note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. This is rather important when comparing to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: @dbush It worked! Thank you!! But do you know why it worked on my Mac terminal even though the type of ch is char and it didn't work on Linux terminal?

Comment: Some compilers default `char` to signed, others default it to `unsigned`. When it's unsigned, `ch != EOF` is always true and you keep reading past the end of the file.

Comment: The problem is that `char` is a special type, and unlike any other integer type can be either signed or unsigned. It's up to the compiler to decide, and can differ even when using the same compiler on different systems (or between different compilers on the same system). If `char` is unsigned, then the value `-1` is really `255`. This is different from the `-1` of the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: @Barmar ohh ok! Tnx!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok I get it now! Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

You declare `ch` as a `char`. The `char` type cannot store all values returned by `fgetc()`.

- if `char` is a signed type, both `EOF` and `'\377'` (or `'\xff'`) have the value `-1` and the test `ch == EOF` is true at end of file but also if the file contains a byte with all bits set.  `char` is signed be default on your Mac, so the program behaves as expected on this system, but it would fail to output the complete file contents if the file contains a `'\377'` byte.
- if `char` is an unsigned type, when `fgetc(fdin)` returns `EOF`, ie: `-1`, this value is converted to an `unsigned char` and becomes `255` which is different from `EOF`, so the test `while (ch != EOF)` is never true and the program prints the `'\xff'` character indefinitely. The linux terminal expects UTF-8 encoded output, so the character `'\xff'` is an invalid character and is displayed as a question mark.  This explains the behavior on linux.

Change the type of `ch` to `int` to fix this problem and get reliable operation on both target architectures.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // input from user
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid number of arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *fname = argv[1];
    // Open file
    FILE *fdin = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (fdin == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", fname, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fdin)) != EOF) {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(fdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very common. `fgetc` returns `int` for a reason.

You need to declare `ch` as `int` not `char`

```
int ch = fgetc(fdin);
```